# need to turn JSON values into keys

Tags: python, json

I have some json that I would like to transform from this:

```
           [
            {
               "name":"field1",
               "intValue":"1"
            },
            {
               "name":"field2",
               "intValue":"2"
            },
            ...
            {
               "name":"fieldN",
               "intValue":"N"
            }
            ]
```

into this:

```
{ "field1" : "1",
  "field2" : "2",
  ...
  "fieldN" : "N",
}
```

For each pair, I need to change the value of the `name` field to a key, and the values of the `intValue` field to a value. This doesn't seem like flattening or denormalizing. Are there any tools that might do this out-of-the-box, or will this have to be brute-forced? What's the most pythonic way to accomplish this?

Comment: are there _a tremendous number_? otherwise you can just iterate over `"parameters"`, packing a new dict

Comment: @ti7 yes there are about 50.

Comment: good news - creating a new dict here and packing it from the old one will be fast and painless! depending on use case, you would need to worry about performance around perhaps 1000 entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
parameters = [ # assuming this is loaded already
    {
        "name":"field1",
        "intValue":"1"
    },
    {
        "name":"field2",
        "intValue":"2"
    },
    {
        "name":"fieldN",
        "intValue":"N"
    }
]

 

field_int_map = dict()

for p in parameters:
    field_int_map[p['name']] = p['intValue']
```

yields `{'field1': '1', 'field2': '2', 'fieldN': 'N'}`

#### or as a dict comprehension

```py
field_int_map = {p['name']:p['intValue'] for p in parameters}
```

This works to combine the `name` attribute with the `intValue` as key:value pairs, but the result is a dictionary instead of the original input type which was a list.

Answer (score 1):

Use [dictionary comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
json_dct = {"parameters":
            [
                {
                    "name":"field1",
                    "intValue":"1"
                },
                {
                    "name":"field2",
                    "intValue":"2"
                },
                {
                    "name":"fieldN",
                    "intValue":"N"
                }
            ]}

dct = {d["name"]: d["intValue"] for d in json_dct["parameters"]}
print(dct)
# {'field1': '1', 'field2': '2', 'fieldN': 'N'}
```